# HP Printer odd behaviour in Vista Home Basic

Tags: windows-vista, printer

I Have a HP 1018 printer. In my previous PC (with vista home premium) it worked just fine, and still works.
In my new PC, which came with vista home basic, the printing almost never works. What happens is as follows

1 - I install the printer, windows says its ok.
2 - I send a document to print.
3 - Printer screen (spool) shows the document for 1 or 2 seconds and then it disappear.

For two times it worked after numerous reinstallations, and after I restart my computer it stop working again.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, on Vista Business 64, with the same printer. Any one?

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem I have with HP's other printer.

Make a batch file as below to stop and restart printer service and save it as resetPrinter.cmd in your windows directory.

```
net stop Spooler
net start Spooler
```

Now, when every it misbehaves, you just go to run command window and type `resetPrinter` and press `Enter`.

Thats what I also do.

**Tip:** Because it needs Run as administrator, in your windows folder, go to the properties of `resetPrinter.cmd` file. Select `Run as Administrator` check box in `Compatibility` tab. This will prompt you to run as administrator every time. But this will save you from opening up an elevated command prompt to run `resetPrinter` command.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to check HP's [website](http://support.hp.com) to see if this is a known issue. You can and should download the latest drivers for your printer if they are available.

Also, its possible however unlikely that you accidentally selected the Print to file as the port the printer is attached to. This would produce similar behavior. (Though it would prompt for a file name with each print job)

Answer (score 0):

The edition of Windows should not make a difference (other than if one was 32bit and the other was 64bit).

I just had a client who had problems with an HP printer on Vista, the shipped CD had bad incompatible drivers despite it saying they were.

I would first uninstall all trace of HP software and drivers then [Click here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=1814094&lang=en&) and download the latest version of the drivers and then reinstall from scratch.