# HP Printer odd behaviour in Vista Home Basic (further information)

Tags: windows-vista, printer

I [asked a question](https://superuser.com/questions/45773/hp-printer-odd-behaviour-in-vista-home-basic) some time ago and now I have some further information.
I have been doing this for weeks now so I am sure that this is really happening this way.
I have an old laptop where my printer used to work and a new laptop in wich the problems described in my prior question happen.
Every day I have to send one printing job to the old laptop via the network, it prints, and then I can plug the printer to my new laptop and it works until I shut it down. Every day.
The questions are:

-What happens when I print via the network that makes local printing start to work?

-what can I do to solve it without have to send one job every day to the other laptop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure that you have exactly the same printer driver on the new machine as you have on the old one.

You can use [Driver Magician Lite](http://www.drivermagician.com/Lite.htm) to compare both drivers, and also to export it from the old machine to the new.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. But it gives the very same driver version (6.2.1.0 - 12-10-2007 - HP Laserjet 1018). Any further idea?

Comment: My other idea has to do with fonts: Is it possible that your print job uses fonts that the printer doesn't have, and that the old machine is set to include with the print, but not the new? I don't know enough about your print software to be more specific.

Comment: It worked! Even both having the same version, backing up in the old and restoring in the new one makes it work. Thanks a lot.